# Is it possible for mods to 'force accept' answers on questions where the account of the (question-)author is dead

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Is it possible for mods to 'force accept' answers on questions where the account of the (question-)author is dead/is offline for a long time?

I'm asking that question because I'm seeing posts like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195049/antivirus-warns-about-processes-trying-to-access-my-webcam) where the answer was already posted but not accepted since the person who posted the question was offline for over a year.

My problem with this is, that the bot called [Community](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) randomly pokes old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention and reappear in the 'active' feed, which also brings already answered(but with no accepted answer) questions back to the feed for no actual reason.

Comment: Note that this does exist as a feature on (some tiers) of Stack Overflow for Teams, where admins of the Team can accept an answer on the question author's behalf if the question author's Team profile has been deactivated. However, that is not a feature on public Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, mods cannot accept an answer for the Asker. The community upvotes the best answer.

Questions with no upvoted Answers get bumped to the main feed, so your best action is to vote.

Comment: Does the Community-bot stop with editing(and bringing them back in the feed) when you upvote an answer and/or downvote the question?

Comment: That's right. Only the questions with unanswered or unvoted answers get bumped.